# Office 365 SharePoint WebProxy calling https/SSL service fails with error "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom

I'm using the SharePoint web proxy in an SharePoint App to call an external service (which I control). I set the service up to use SSL and it seems SharePoint has a problem with my certificate (or something) since it fails with the above error when calling the service with https. If I use http instead of https the call works fine. The app.manifest is correct. If I call the same service from the browser using https it works fine.

Also if I put the service on free Azure web sites which provides SSL automatically and have the SP WebProxy call that it also works OK. So SP must be happy with the Azure SSL certificate

It seems that it is something specific to my SSL certificate that SharePoint doesn't like.

Since it is Office 365 I don't control the server so I can't install certificates.

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question so I will just comment and say that I just tried this again this morning and the call worked with https via  the SP Web Proxy. I don't know why it is working now. Maybe the certificate hadn't propagated everywhere? This is really something I do not know much about I am still a little concerned with on-prem where the servers are behind firewalls. Do certificates needs to be installed there in order for the https calls to work?

Answer (score 1):

Who issued the certificate you are using on the external service?

It sounds like it was issued by someone trusted by your browser, but not by Microsoft. I don't know if they publish a list of what certificate authorities they trust (I searched and couldn't find one), but I guess a good starting point would be the IE default list.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the links from the Microsoft support and TechNet site below since I host the web site on Azure.  GoDaddy supplied the certificate and they are on the list of CA's in Microsoft's certificate program.  The "caller" of the web site is not the actual browser, it is an instance of SharePoint online (in Office 365) calling it from the server.  [MS Support](https://support2.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?scid=sw;en;3864&showpage=1),  [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14215.windows-and-windows-phone-8-ssl-root-certificate-program-member-cas.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint is the tenant you are having trouble with? You can find this in the response headers on any request (e.g. MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4121)

Comment: For Office 365 SharePoint the header is 16.0.0.4121, as in your reply.  When the App is used on-prem I guess it could be anything.  BTW I just tried this again this morning and the call worked with https!  I don't know why.  Maybe the certificate hadn't propagated everywhere?  I am still a little concerned with on-prem where the servers are behind firewalls.  Thanks for the reply.